# PHP ORM avoid recursion

Tags: php, database, orm

how can I avoid the recursion in following code? I have **two database tables**:

1. Company (company)
2. Point of Sale (pos)

with following **relations**:

1. A company has many pos
2. A pos has one company

**Exemplary classes**:

```
class Company
{
    protected $_pos;

    public function addPos(Pos $pos)
    {
        $this->_pos[] = $pos;
    }

    public function getPos()
    {
        return $this->_pos;
    }
}

class Pos
{
    protected $_company;

    public function setCompany(Company $company)
    {
        $this->_company = $company;
    }

    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->_company;
    }
}
```

Now I will show you the problem:

```
$company = new Company();

$pos1 = new Pos();
$pos1->setCompany($company);

$pos2 = new Pos();
$pos2->setCompany($company);

$company->addPos($pos1);
$company->addPos($pos2);
```

My goal is to be able to have following methods that return the specific object:

```
$company = $pos->getCompany();
```

and

```
$pos = $company->getPos();
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Where is recursion here btw?

Comment: A pos object will have a company object that has an array of pos objects and so on and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I found what I was looking for: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33595